# IDangero.us Swiper framework does not work properly

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Sometime swiper does not respond to any onclick action. In this situation, to get it works again I have to do one of these things:

1. Close all existing tabs, then close browser and open it again
2. Open development tool, start profiler on heap recording and leave it running (swiper will stop working if I stop profiler)
3. Open development tool, then activate mobile mode

Anyone knows what was wrong in my situation?